# Why is Windows 8.1 using an external USB drive as the primary for .EXE Decompressions?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive

Funny issue here. 
I have bought a Samsung 250GB SSD drive and installed a fresh copy of windows 8 on it which I updated to 8.1. in addition to this drive this machine also has 2 internal drives and 1 USB external hard drive.

for some reason when i try to install applications from a compressesed .EXE file, for example SQL server.. the decompressed filed automatically goes to drive F: which is the External Hard Drive. when disconnecting it, the decompression goes to drive D: which is one of the internal drives but not the primary SSD where windows is installed.

Why does this happen, and how could i set primary drive C to be the default target for decompression?

Comment: There is probably a registry entry to set where applications target their temporary expand location...?

Comment: Some installs use a disk location with the most or much available space, for the temp files that breakout. It is only about the program or update finding a big empty space and using it. Are you saying the program itself is being installed there?  or just leftovers from an install?

Answer (score 3):

Windows always expands Setup files to the drive with most free space which is in your case the external Drive when no [ROOTDRIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is set.

> If it is not an administrative installation, or if the installer can
>   find no network drives, the **installer sets ROOTDRIVE to the local
>   drive that can be written to having the most free space**.

Comment: this may explain why I see sometimes Windows extracts Windows installation files or update files to another drive instead of C:

Comment: Thanks that would explain it, but is there a way to set the ROOTDRIVE manually? can i still change this setting to always decompress to a specific drive?

Comment: You can use 7zip to extract the installer to any location you want and run the included setup.exe